# Raster images in GeoServer without WMS

Tags: raster, geoserver

Is there any available way to access raster images through GeoServer without WMS? (to a large number of images)

Comment: you can also use WCS to request the actual raster data.

Comment: @Appletree, to consume as a service or access as a store?

Comment: @artwork21 as a service with some functions ( metadata view probably)